# Angular directive doesn't work with click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How add buttons with on click handler to template in directive ?

I use this script, but it not work in controller.

I'm new in angular. I got this script from https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive/blob/master/README.md

```
(function() {
  var module;

  module = angular.module('treeGrid', []);

  module.directive('treeGrid', [
    '$timeout', '$compile', function ($timeout, $compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //templateUrl:'tree-grid-template.html',
        //template:"<div><table class=\"table table-bordered table-striped tree-grid\"><thead class=\"text-primary\"><tr><th>{{expandingProperty}}</th><th ng-repeat=\"col in colDefinitions\">{{col.displayName || col.field}}</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr ng-repeat=\"row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid\" ng-class=\"'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')\" class=\"tree-grid-row\"><td class=\"text-primary\"><a ng-click=\"user_clicks_branch(row.branch)\"><i ng-class=\"row.tree_icon\" ng-click=\"row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded\" class=\"indented tree-icon\"></i></a><span class=\"indented tree-label\">{{row.branch[expandingProperty]}}</span></td><td ng-repeat=\"col in colDefinitions\">{{row.branch[col.field]}}</td></tr></tbody><table></div>",
        template:
          "<div>\
              <table class=\"table table-bordered table-striped tree-grid\">\
                  <thead class=\"text-primary\">\
                  <tr>\
                      <th>{{expandingProperty}}</th>\
                      <th ng-repeat=\"col in colDefinitions\">{{col.displayName || col.field}}</th>\
                      <th>Actions</th>\
                  </tr>\
                  </thead>\
                  <tbody>\
                  <tr ng-repeat=\"row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid\"\
                      ng-class=\"'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')\" class=\"tree-grid-row\">\
                      <td class=\"text-primary\"><a ng-click=\"user_clicks_branch(row.branch)\"><i ng-class=\"row.tree_icon\"\
                                 ng-click=\"row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded\"\
                                 class=\"indented tree-icon\"></i>\
                          </a><span class=\"indented tree-label\" ng-click=\"user_clicks_branch(row.branch)\">\
                            {{row.branch[expandingProperty]}}</span>\
                      </td>\
                      <td ng-repeat=\"col in colDefinitions\">{{row.branch[col.field]}}</td>\
                      <td data-title=\"''\" style=\"width: 150px\">\
                            <button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"handleActions.edit(row)\">\
                                <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></i> \
                            </button>\
                            <button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"createWindow()\">\
                                <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus\"></i> \
                            </button>\
                            <button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-show=\"row.deletable\" ng-click=\"handleActions.delete(row)\">\
                                <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i>\
                            </button>\
                        </td>\
                  </tr>\
                  </tbody>\
              </table>\
          </div>",
        //template:
        //  "<div>\
        //      <table class=\"table table-bordered table-striped tree-grid\">\
        //          <thead class=\"text-primary\">\
        //          <tr>\
        //              <th>{{expandingProperty}}</th>\
        //              <th ng-repeat=\"col in colDefinitions\">{{col.displayName || col.field}}</th>\
        //          </tr>\
        //          </thead>\
        //          <tbody>\
        //          <tr ng-repeat=\"row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid\"\
        //              ng-class=\"'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')\" class=\"tree-grid-row\">\
        //              <td class=\"text-primary\"><a ng-click=\"user_clicks_branch(row.branch)\"><i ng-class=\"row.tree_icon\"\
        //                         ng-click=\"row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded\"\
        //                         class=\"indented tree-icon\"></i>\
        //                  </a><span class=\"indented tree-label\" ng-click=\"user_clicks_branch(row.branch)\">\
        //                    {{row.branch[expandingProperty]}}</span>\
        //              </td>\
        //              <td ng-repeat=\"col in colDefinitions\">{{row.branch[col.field]}}</td>\
        //          </tr>\
        //          </tbody>\
        //      </table>\
        //  </div>",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          treeData: '=',
          colDefs:'=',
          expandOn:'=',
          onSelect: '&',
          initialSelection: '@',
          treeControl: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var error, expandingProperty, expand_all_parents, expand_level, for_all_ancestors, for_each_branch, get_parent, n, on_treeData_change, select_branch, selected_branch, tree;

          error = function(s) {
            console.log('ERROR:' + s);
            debugger;
            return void 0;
          };

          if (attrs.iconExpand == null) {
            attrs.iconExpand = 'icon-plus  glyphicon glyphicon-plus  fa fa-plus';
          }
          if (attrs.iconCollapse == null) {
            attrs.iconCollapse = 'icon-minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus fa fa-minus';
          }
          if (attrs.iconLeaf == null) {
            attrs.iconLeaf = 'icon-file  glyphicon glyphicon-file  fa fa-file';
          }
          if (attrs.expandLevel == null) {
            attrs.expandLevel = '3';
          }

          expand_level = parseInt(attrs.expandLevel, 10);

          if (!scope.treeData) {
            alert('no treeData defined for the tree!');
            return;
          }
          if (scope.treeData.length == null) {
            if (treeData.label != null) {
              scope.treeData = [treeData];
            } else {
              alert('treeData should be an array of root branches');
              return;
            }
          }
          if(attrs.expandOn){            
            expandingProperty = scope.expandOn;
            scope.expandingProperty = scope.expandOn;
          }
          else{
            var _firstRow = scope.treeData[0], 
                _keys = Object.keys(_firstRow);
            for(var i =0, len = _keys.length; i<len; i++){
              if(typeof(_firstRow[_keys[i]])=='string'){
                expandingProperty = _keys[i];
                break;
              }
            }
            if(!expandingProperty) expandingProperty = _keys[0];
            scope.expandingProperty = expandingProperty;
          }

          if(!attrs.colDefs){
            var _col_defs = [], _firstRow = scope.treeData[0], _unwantedColumn = ['children', 'level', 'expanded', expandingProperty];
            for(var idx in _firstRow){
              if(_unwantedColumn.indexOf(idx)==-1)
                _col_defs.push({field:idx});
            }            
            scope.colDefinitions = _col_defs;
          }
          else{
            console.log(scope.colDefs);
            scope.colDefinitions = scope.colDefs;
          }

          for_each_branch = function(f) {
            var do_f, root_branch, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
            do_f = function(branch, level) {
              var child, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
              f(branch, level);
              if (branch.children != null) {
                _ref = branch.children;
                _results = [];
                for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                  child = _ref[_i];
                  _results.push(do_f(child, level + 1));
                }
                return _results;
              }
            };
            _ref = scope.treeData;
            _results = [];
            for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
              root_branch = _ref[_i];
              _results.push(do_f(root_branch, 1));
            }
            return _results;
          };
          selected_branch = null;
          select_branch = function(branch) {
            if (!branch) {
              if (selected_branch != null) {
                selected_branch.selected = false;
              }
              selected_branch = null;
              return;
            }
            if (branch !== selected_branch) {
              if (selected_branch != null) {
                selected_branch.selected = false;
              }
              branch.selected = true;
              selected_branch = branch;
              expand_all_parents(branch);
              if (branch.onSelect != null) {
                return $timeout(function() {
                  return branch.onSelect(branch);
                });
              } else {
                if (scope.onSelect != null) {
                  return $timeout(function() {
                    return scope.onSelect({
                      branch: branch
                    });
                  });
                }
              }
            }
          };
          scope.user_clicks_branch = function(branch) {
            if (branch !== selected_branch) {
              return select_branch(branch);
            }
          };
          get_parent = function(child) {
            var parent;
            parent = void 0;
            if (child.parent_uid) {
              for_each_branch(function(b) {
                if (b.uid === child.parent_uid) {
                  return parent = b;
                }
              });
            }
            return parent;
          };
          for_all_ancestors = function(child, fn) {
            var parent;
            parent = get_parent(child);
            if (parent != null) {
              fn(parent);
              return for_all_ancestors(parent, fn);
            }
          };
          expand_all_parents = function(child) {
            return for_all_ancestors(child, function(b) {
              return b.expanded = true;
            });
          };

          scope.tree_rows = [];

          on_treeData_change = function() {
            var add_branch_to_list, root_branch, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
            for_each_branch(function(b, level) {
              if (!b.uid) {
                return b.uid = "" + Math.random();
              }
            });
            for_each_branch(function(b) {
              var child, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
              if (angular.isArray(b.children)) {
                _ref = b.children;
                _results = [];
                for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                  child = _ref[_i];
                  _results.push(child.parent_uid = b.uid);
                }
                return _results;
              }
            });
            scope.tree_rows = [];
            for_each_branch(function(branch) {
              var child, f;
              if (branch.children) {
                if (branch.children.length > 0) {
                  f = function(e) {
                    if (typeof e === 'string') {
                      return {
                        label: e,
                        children: []
                      };
                    } else {
                      return e;
                    }
                  };
                  return branch.children = (function() {
                    var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
                    _ref = branch.children;
                    _results = [];
                    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                      child = _ref[_i];
                      _results.push(f(child));
                    }
                    return _results;
                  })();
                }
              } else {
                return branch.children = [];
              }
            });
            add_branch_to_list = function(level, branch, visible) {
              var child, child_visible, tree_icon, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
              if (branch.expanded == null) {
                branch.expanded = false;
              }
              if (!branch.children || branch.children.length === 0) {
                tree_icon = attrs.iconLeaf;
              } else {
                if (branch.expanded) {
                  tree_icon = attrs.iconCollapse;
                } else {
                  tree_icon = attrs.iconExpand;
                }
              }
              branch.level = level;
              scope.tree_rows.push({
                level: level,
                branch: branch,                
                label: branch[expandingProperty],                
                tree_icon: tree_icon,
                visible: visible
              });
              if (branch.children != null) {
                _ref = branch.children;
                _results = [];
                for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                  child = _ref[_i];
                  child_visible = visible && branch.expanded;
                  _results.push(add_branch_to_list(level + 1, child, child_visible));
                }
                return _results;
              }
            };
            _ref = scope.treeData;
            _results = [];
            for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
              root_branch = _ref[_i];
              _results.push(add_branch_to_list(1, root_branch, true));
            }
            return _results;
          };

          scope.$watch('treeData', on_treeData_change, true);

          if (attrs.initialSelection != null) {
            for_each_branch(function(b) {
              if (b.label === attrs.initialSelection) {
                return $timeout(function() {
                  return select_branch(b);
                });
              }
            });
          }
          n = scope.treeData.length;
          for_each_branch(function(b, level) {
            b.level = level;
            return b.expanded = b.level < expand_level;
          });
          if (scope.treeControl != null) {
            if (angular.isObject(scope.treeControl)) {
              tree = scope.treeControl;
              tree.expand_all = function() {
                return for_each_branch(function(b, level) {
                  return b.expanded = true;
                });
              };
              tree.collapse_all = function() {
                return for_each_branch(function(b, level) {
                  return b.expanded = false;
                });
              };
              tree.get_first_branch = function() {
                n = scope.treeData.length;
                if (n > 0) {
                  return scope.treeData[0];
                }
              };
              tree.select_first_branch = function() {
                var b;
                b = tree.get_first_branch();
                return tree.select_branch(b);
              };
              tree.get_selected_branch = function() {
                return selected_branch;
              };
              tree.get_parent_branch = function(b) {
                return get_parent(b);
              };
              tree.select_branch = function(b) {
                select_branch(b);
                return b;
              };
              tree.get_children = function(b) {
                return b.children;
              };
              tree.select_parent_branch = function(b) {
                var p;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = tree.get_selected_branch();
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  p = tree.get_parent_branch(b);
                  if (p != null) {
                    tree.select_branch(p);
                    return p;
                  }
                }
              };
              tree.add_branch = function(parent, new_branch) {
                if (parent != null) {
                  parent.children.push(new_branch);
                  parent.expanded = true;
                } else {
                  scope.treeData.push(new_branch);
                }
                return new_branch;
              };
              tree.add_root_branch = function(new_branch) {
                tree.add_branch(null, new_branch);
                return new_branch;
              };
              tree.expand_branch = function(b) {
                if (b == null) {
                  b = tree.get_selected_branch();
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  b.expanded = true;
                  return b;
                }
              };
              tree.collapse_branch = function(b) {
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  b.expanded = false;
                  return b;
                }
              };
              tree.get_siblings = function(b) {
                var p, siblings;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  p = tree.get_parent_branch(b);
                  if (p) {
                    siblings = p.children;
                  } else {
                    siblings = scope.treeData;
                  }
                  return siblings;
                }
              };
              tree.get_next_sibling = function(b) {
                var i, siblings;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  siblings = tree.get_siblings(b);
                  n = siblings.length;
                  i = siblings.indexOf(b);
                  if (i < n) {
                    return siblings[i + 1];
                  }
                }
              };
              tree.get_prev_sibling = function(b) {
                var i, siblings;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                siblings = tree.get_siblings(b);
                n = siblings.length;
                i = siblings.indexOf(b);
                if (i > 0) {
                  return siblings[i - 1];
                }
              };
              tree.select_next_sibling = function(b) {
                var next;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  next = tree.get_next_sibling(b);
                  if (next != null) {
                    return tree.select_branch(next);
                  }
                }
              };
              tree.select_prev_sibling = function(b) {
                var prev;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  prev = tree.get_prev_sibling(b);
                  if (prev != null) {
                    return tree.select_branch(prev);
                  }
                }
              };
              tree.get_first_child = function(b) {
                var _ref;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  if (((_ref = b.children) != null ? _ref.length : void 0) > 0) {
                    return b.children[0];
                  }
                }
              };
              tree.get_closest_ancestor_next_sibling = function(b) {
                var next, parent;
                next = tree.get_next_sibling(b);
                if (next != null) {
                  return next;
                } else {
                  parent = tree.get_parent_branch(b);
                  return tree.get_closest_ancestor_next_sibling(parent);
                }
              };
              tree.get_next_branch = function(b) {
                var next;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  next = tree.get_first_child(b);
                  if (next != null) {
                    return next;
                  } else {
                    next = tree.get_closest_ancestor_next_sibling(b);
                    return next;
                  }
                }
              };
              tree.select_next_branch = function(b) {
                var next;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  next = tree.get_next_branch(b);
                  if (next != null) {
                    tree.select_branch(next);
                    return next;
                  }
                }
              };
              tree.last_descendant = function(b) {
                var last_child;
                if (b == null) {
                  debugger;
                }
                n = b.children.length;
                if (n === 0) {
                  return b;
                } else {
                  last_child = b.children[n - 1];
                  return tree.last_descendant(last_child);
                }
              };
              tree.get_prev_branch = function(b) {
                var parent, prev_sibling;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  prev_sibling = tree.get_prev_sibling(b);
                  if (prev_sibling != null) {
                    return tree.last_descendant(prev_sibling);
                  } else {
                    parent = tree.get_parent_branch(b);
                    return parent;
                  }
                }
              };
              return tree.select_prev_branch = function(b) {
                var prev;
                if (b == null) {
                  b = selected_branch;
                }
                if (b != null) {
                  prev = tree.get_prev_branch(b);
                  if (prev != null) {
                    tree.select_branch(prev);
                    return prev;
                  }
                }
              };
            }
          }
        }
      };
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);
```

Comment: I want to help, but there's too much blood in my eyes.

Comment: @m59 This is why I moved most of my projects to ReactJS at this point.  Angular directive templates are disgusting :/

Comment: @Mike the template should be in another file and using `templateUrl`, then included with `$templateCache` to optimize... Including the template inline was just one of the many amazing things about this code.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you have added three buttons to the template in the directive:

```
<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"handleActions.edit(row)\">\
  <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></i> \
</button>\
<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"createWindow()\">\
  <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus\"></i> \
</button>\
<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-show=\"row.deletable\" ng-click=\"handleActions.delete(row)\">\
  <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i>\
</button>\
```

And you have added ng-click to them. Now, the functions that will be executed on the ng-click event, should be part of the [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

In this case, when defining your directive, you are declaring a scope in the definition:

```
scope: {
      treeData: '=',
      colDefs:'=',
      expandOn:'=',
      onSelect: '&',
      initialSelection: '@',
      treeControl: '='
    }
```

So, you have created an [Isolated scope](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope). This means that the functions `createWindow`, `edit` and `delete` must be part of the directive scope.

You have two options, the dirty way: Copy your functions to the directive:

```
module.directive('treeGrid', [
[...]

<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"edit(row)\">\
  <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></i> \
</button>\
<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"createWindow()\">\
  <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus\"></i> \
</button>\
<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-show=\"row.deletable\" ng-click=\"delete(row)\">\
  <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i>\
</button>\

[...]
scope.user_clicks_branch = function(branch) {
        if (branch !== selected_branch) {
          return select_branch(branch);
        }
      };

// new code
scope.createWindow = function() {
    // your createWindow code
}
scope.edit = function(row) {
    // your edit row code
}
scope.delete = function(row) {
    // your delete row code
}

[...]
  ]);
}).call(this);
```

Or you can pass the handlers as parameters using the [expression binding (&)](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/) (like the code is doing for the onSelect handler):

```
module.directive('treeGrid', [
[...]

<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"onEdit(row)\">\
  <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></i> \
</button>\
<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"createWindow()\">\
  <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus\"></i> \
</button>\
<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-show=\"row.deletable\" ng-click=\"onDelete(row)\">\
  <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i>\
</button>\

[...]
scope: {
      treeData: '=',
      colDefs:'=',
      expandOn:'=',
      onSelect: '&',
      createWindow: '&',
      onEdit: '&',
      onDelete: '&',
      initialSelection: '@',
      treeControl: '='
    }
[...]
  ]);
}).call(this);
```

Comment: A can't use templateUrl because I have ng-class=\"'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')\" class=\"tree-grid-row\">\ which throw exception

Answer (score 0):

If you want only add some buttons to a column, you can add in columns definition using $scope.col_def in your controller, like this:

```
$scope.col_defs = [{ field: "id" }, 
            {
                field: "Action",
                cellTemplate: $templateCache.get('buttonTemplate.html'),
                cellTemplateScope: {
                    doSomething: function () {                            
                        console.log('call your function here, or put what you want to do');
                    }
                }
            }];
```

and the 'buttonTemplate.html' can be defined in your view, inside the controller, and define the col_defs in the treeGrid:

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">        
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="buttonTemplate.html">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="cellTemplateScope.doSomething()">Do Something</button>
    </script>

    <tree-grid tree-data="yourTreeData" col-defs="col_defs"></tree-grid>
</div>
```

So it will run this template inside your column, and call the function doSomething() when you click on the button, in this case.